# Trying to drop database only if it does not exist by using the db_id function fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

When the database `foo` is not yet created and I I run this

```
IF db_id(N'foo') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  ALTER DATABASE [foo] SET OFFLINE
  GO

  DROP DATABASE [foo]
  GO
END
```

I get a message

> Cannot drop the database 'foo' becuase it does not exist or you do not
>   have permission.

Why?

I have confirmed that the sql statement `select db_id(N'foo')` returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a parsing error, not a runtime error. You can avoid this by removing the `GO` commands (these can't exist inside an `IF` block anyway) and using dynamic SQL.

Why `IF DB_ID()` instead of just putting the `DROP` inside `TRY/CATCH` (or letting it error)?

You may want `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` on the `ALTER`.

```
BEGIN TRY
  ALTER DATABASE foo SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
  DROP DATABASE foo;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'Failure or database does not exist.';
END CATCH
```

Or

```
IF DB_ID(N'foo') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'ALTER DATABASE foo SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE foo;';
END
```

Of course this approach (`OFFLINE` first) will leave the data and log files intact, which means that if they were created in the default location, if you try to create the same database again, you'll first need to move or rename those files, or manually specify different names in the new file specification.

Comment: I wish I never had to specify where those files should be...

Answer (score 3):

Below should work

```
If exists (select 1 from master.sys.databases where name ='db you want to check')
  Begin
    Alter database db-name set restricted user with rollback immediate ;
    Drop database db-name;
  End
Else 
  Print 'db does not exist '
```

Note: If you offline the database and drop the database, the mdf and ldf files will still remain on disk and you have to manually delete them.